# How to paint in smooth line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to paint between **smooth line** and **smooth line** or other.

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,3.5);
  \coordinate (A) at (1,2);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,3);
  \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);
  \coordinate (D) at (4,2);
  \draw[name path=AA,thick,red]plot[smooth,tension=0.7] coordinates {(O)(A)(B)(C)(D)};
  \draw[name path=AB,thick,dashed](0,2.5)--(4,2.5);
  \path[name intersections={of=AA and AB}];
  \fill[gray](intersection-1)--plot[smooth,tension=0.7] coordinates {(O)(A)(B)(C)(D)}--(intersection-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output is this.
[image]

but I want to paint following area.
[image]

Comment: You could use `spath3` to split the curve at the intersections with the straight and remove all other parts. Alternatively, you could just do `\clip (intersection-1) rectangle (intersection-2|-0,-1.5);` before `\fill[gray] …;`.

Comment: You could use `pgfplots` with `fill between` with option `split` and then specify a style for the segment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the basic approach: Clipping before filling the area.

The `backgrounds` library and its key `on background layer` is used to place the filling behind the already drawn paths so that we don't have to use them again. To not have to repeat (and recalculate) the curved path, I'm using `save path` to save the path in a macro. It can be retrieved with `use path`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 3.5);
\coordinate (A) at (1, 2  );
\coordinate (B) at (2, 3  );
\coordinate (C) at (3, 1.5);
\coordinate (D) at (4, 2  );
\draw[red,    name path=curve, save path=\curve]
  plot[smooth, tension=0.7, samples at ={O, A, B, C, D}](\x);
\draw[dashed, name path=line] (0,2.5) -- (4, 2.5);
\begin{scope}[on background layer, name intersections={of=curve and line, sort by=line}]
  \clip (intersection-1) rectangle (intersection-2 |- C); % C is lowest point
  \fill[gray, use path=\curve];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for recommending me the best answer.
By the way, I have a question of this code.
- What does  `sort by=line` in scope option mean ?

Comment: The [`sort by` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#tikz/intersection/sort:by) is part of the intersection calculation. This makes sure the intersections are sorted by the order they appear on the `line` path. I realize now that there wouldn't be a difference either way because both paths go strictly in the same direction (and so do the intersections). For more complex paths it is more useful.